# Change Rememberme-Cookie in a Webfilter

Tags: java, cookies, jakarta-ee, remember-me, webfiltering

I'm trying to change the Domain and Path of a Cookie in a Webfilter.
The Cookie is added to the Response by the Soteria RememberMeInterceptor.

This is my Webfilter:

```java
@WebFilter(filterName = "DomainCookieFilter",
            urlPatterns = {"/*"},
            dispatcherTypes = {DispatcherType.ASYNC, DispatcherType.REQUEST})
public class DomainCookieFilter implements Filter {
    
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DomainCookieFilter.class.getSimpleName());

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        logger.info("DomainCookieFilter invoked!!!");
        chain.doFilter(request, new DomainCookieResponseWrapper((HttpServletResponse) response));

    }
}
```

And this the ResponseWrapper:

```java
public class DomainCookieResponseWrapper extends HttpServletResponseWrapper {
    
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DomainCookieResponseWrapper.class.getSimpleName());

    public DomainCookieResponseWrapper(HttpServletResponse response) {
        super(response);
    }

    @Override
    public void addCookie(Cookie cookie) {
        logger.info("Add Cookie: " + cookie.getName());
        if(cookie.getName().equals("JREMEMBERMEID") && cookie.getMaxAge() != 0) {
            cookie.setDomain(".domain.local");
            cookie.setPath("/");
            logger.info("Add Cookie: changed Domain");
        }
        super.addCookie(cookie);
    }
}
```

The DomainCookieResponseWrapper.addCookie-Method is never called, and I don't understand why.
So what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

A few tries later I came to the conclusion that Authenticationrequests are not filtered.
I finally came up with a different aproach. 
I wrote another RemembermeInterceptor preceding the default one, in wich the Response is replaced by my Responsewrapper.

```java
@Interceptor
@RememberMe
@Priority(PLATFORM_BEFORE + 209)
public class PreRememberMeInterceptor implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object intercept(InvocationContext ctx) throws Exception {
        
        Object[] newParams = { ctx.getParameters()[0],
                new DomainCookieResponseWrapper((HttpServletResponse) ctx.getParameters()[1]), 
                ctx.getParameters()[2] };
        
        ctx.setParameters(newParams);

        return ctx.proceed();
    }

}
```

This maybe isn't the best Solution, but it works.
If anyone has a better approach, please let me know.

Comment: What you did is the correct approach. An authentication mechanism is principally executed before the Servlet chain is entered, and therefor Servlet filters aren't applicable to them. An HttpAuthenticationMechanism in Jakarta EE is always a CDI bean though, and it also must be based on a low-level Jakarta Authentication ServerAuthModule. Both can be replaced/augmented via standard APIs. Remember-me is always an interceptor on an authentication mechanism, which can altered using the std CPI API, ad you did.

Comment: p.s. I did encounter exactly the same issue in practice as you had for a web app I worked on, so I think we should simplify this common case of adding a domain (and other things) to a cookie.

I feel some sort of CookieWriter, were ALL cookies pass through would be the easiest solution.